# Overwritten Mac note

Tags: macos, notes.app, data-recovery

I was typing and I accidentally hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (Select All) and then I continued typing. That wiped my entire note and <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (Undo) didn't work. Time Machine and iCloud weren't on, it was locally stored and I only have one drive.

I then tried to recover it with a data recovery software and here's what I found on the data recovery software. (Apologies for the image you'll have to zoom in) It's the NotesV7.storedata file dated right BEFORE I wiped my text. But the thing is I do not know what to do next. Do I retrieve it and replace the old one? Will my notes even reappear?

There's 8 months' worth of work in there and I hope somebody can help.

[image]

Comment: RE: (Apologies for the image you'll have to zoom in) ... Is the some reason you could not have just taken a normal screenshot of the window and attached it instead of using a cell phone?

Comment: None whatsoever, it just happened.

Answer (score 2):

There’s nothing to recover.

- Notes is autosaved the moment you make a change, so it saved your deletion
- You didn’t delete the file, you *changed* it’s contents so recovery software can’t help.  No software can distinguish the difference between “Oops” and “I meant to do that”
- Cloud storage isn’t back up, it’s file synchronization for *availability* everywhere.  That saved file was synced to all of your devices when it changed.
- Time machine would be the best way to protect your data. This needs to be configured and used.

Now, if you do use iCloud, but it just wasn't “on” during this period, it may be your saving grace.  Using a *different* computer, log into your iCloud account (iCloud drive) via a web browser and download a copy of your notes.  Make a backup of this file!

Now, if you log back into your computer, you can copy the notes back and have it sync.  Then turn on a Time Machine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104897/discussion-on-answer-by-allan-overwritten-mac-note).

Comment: I did find this, can you try this out and be so kind as to walk me through it? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8402323

Answer (score -2):

The other device where iCloud is logged in can be used to recover it. The condition is to take it offline.

I keep my iPhone in low power mode, so notes won't sync unless I open the app. So if something like that happened to me, I'd just put the phone on airplane mode, and copy paste the note.